# How can I solve the problem of 2 issues were found when checking AAR metadata?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

I still get the problem of "2 issues were found when checking AAR metadata" every time I build my project even for a simple "hello world". I attach the buld.Gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.mycompany.myapplication'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapplication"
        minSdk 31
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

I uninstalled Android Studio and installed it again - not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android studio flamingo, change compileSdk and targetSdk to 34. for me, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

just update change complieSdk and minSdk 34

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).